# Slow integration of simple integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, special-functions

The simple integral

```
Integrate[ b*Cos[2*Pi*((z - z1)/c)] + a*Sin[2*Pi*((z - z1)/c)], {z, 0, c}]
```

is evaluated much slower if `a` and `b` - coefficients
are some complicated expressions (independent of `z` of course) , e.g.

```
Integrate[ ((4 b^2 BesselI[1, (2 I \[Pi] R)/a]^2 (BesselK[0, (2 b \[Pi])/a] + BesselK[2, (2 b \[Pi])/a]))/(BesselK[0, (2 b \[Pi])/a] - BesselK[2, (2 b \[Pi])/a])*Cos[2 \[Pi] (z - z1)/c] + ((2 \[Pi]^2 BesselI[0, (2 b \[Pi])/a]^2 + a BesselI[1, (2 I b \[Pi])/a]) BesselK[1, (2 \[Pi] R)/a])/(BesselK[0, (2 b \[Pi])/a] - BesselK[2, (2 I b \[Pi])/a])*Sin[2 \[Pi] (z - z1)/c]), {z, 0, c}]
```

Is there any way to speed up such integration ?

Answer (score 3):

A very simple approach that almost always speeds up definite integrals also works here:

```
Simplify@
 Apply[Subtract, 
  Integrate[((4 b^2 BesselI[
            1, (2 I Pi R)/a]^2 (BesselK[0, (2 b Pi)/a] + 
            BesselK[2, (2 b Pi)/a]))/(BesselK[0, (2 b Pi)/a] - 
          BesselK[2, (2 b Pi)/a])*
       Cos[2 Pi (z - z1)/
          c] + ((2 Pi^2 BesselI[0, (2 b Pi)/a]^2 + 
            a BesselI[1, (2 I b Pi)/a]) BesselK[
           1, (2 Pi R)/a])/(BesselK[0, (2 b Pi)/a] - 
          BesselK[2, (2 I b Pi)/a])*Sin[2 Pi (z - z1)/c]), 
    z] /. z -> {0, c}]

(* ==> 0 *)
```

I simply replaced the definite integral by an indefinite integral, then evaluated that result in the desired limits and subtracted the outcomes.

I terms of timings, my solution is slightly slower than the second approach of Michael E2, but arguably much simpler. And it's faster than Michael E2's first approach on my machine.

Comment: Yes, much simpler.  One might add that this shows that the likely reason for the slower definite integral is from `Integrate` verifying convergence or tracking branch cuts.  In this case, it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

#### Op's setup & timing

```
integrand = ((4 b^2 BesselI[1, (2 I π R)/a]^2 (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] + 
          BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a]))/(BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a]) *
     Cos[2 π (z - z1)/c] + ((2 π^2 BesselI[0, (2 b π)/a]^2 + 
          a BesselI[1, (2 I b π)/a]) BesselK[1, (2 π R)/a])/(BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - 
        BesselK[2, (2 I b π)/a]) * Sin[2 π (z - z1)/c]);

Integrate[integrand, {z, 0, c}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.189457, 0}  *)
```

The approaches below are 3-4 times faster.

#### First approach

Replace constant parameters by `Hold[parameter]`.  I show this only for the OP's form of integrand.  The more general second approach below might be adapted to this approach.

```
newint = integrand /. Longest[x_*y_ /; Internal`DependsOnQ[y, z]] :> Hold[x] y
(*
  Cos[(2 π (z - z1))/c] * 
   Hold[(4 b^2 BesselI[1, (2 I π R)/a]^2 (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] + BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a]))/
     (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a])] + 
  Sin[(2 π (z - z1))/c] *
   Hold[((2π^2 BesselI[0, (2 b π)/a]^2 + a BesselI[1, (2 I b π)/a]) BesselK[1, (2 π R)/a])/
     (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - BesselK[2, (2 I b π)/a])] 
*)

Integrate[newint, {z, 0, c}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.048267, 0}  *)
```

#### Second approach

Replace constant parameters with `C[k]`, for `k` = `1`, `2`,....  Here the function `independentOf` goes up (or is it down?) the algebraic expression tree (in terms of `Plus/Times`), from the root to the leaves and identifies expressions that may be replaced with a constant `C[..]`.  In the OP's case the integral depends on the variables `z` and `c`.  One could extend the definition to inspect the arguments of mathematical functions (e.g. `Sin` and `Cos` in the OP's example), but that requires some care, since you wouldn't want to replace `2 Pi` inside a trigonometric function by a `C[k]`.

```
ClearAll[independentOf];
independentOf[expr_, vars_] /; AllTrue[Flatten[vars], ! Internal`DependsOnQ[expr, #] &] := 
  Sow[expr, "expr"];
independentOf[expr : (h : Plus | Times)[__], vars_] :=
  Module[{all}, (* tag to identify whole of  expr  in pattern *)
   all@expr /. all@h[
        x___?(Function[{e}, AllTrue[Flatten[vars], ! Internal`DependsOnQ[e, #] &]]), 
        y___?(Function[{e}, AllTrue[Flatten[vars], Internal`DependsOnQ[e, #] &]])
        ] :> If[h[x] === h[],
      independentOf[#, vars] & /@ expr,
      Sow[h@x, "expr"]; independentOf[#, vars] & /@ h@y]
   ];
```

Apply to the OP's example:

```
constants = Reap[independentOf[integrand, {z, c}], "expr"][[2, 1]]
(*
  {(4 b^2 BesselI[1, (2 I π R)/a]^2 (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] + BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a])) / 
     (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - BesselK[2, (2 b π)/a]),
   ((2 π^2 BesselI[0, (2 b π)/a]^2 + a BesselI[1, (2 I b π)/a]) BesselK[1, (2 π R)/a]) /
     (BesselK[0, (2 b π)/a] - BesselK[2, (2 I b π)/a])}
*)

newint = integrand /. 
  Flatten@MapIndexed[{#*y___ :> C[#2]*y, # + y___ :> C[#2] + y} &, constants]
(*  C[{1}] Cos[(2 π (z - z1))/c] + C[{2}] Sin[(2 π (z - z1))/c]  *)

Integrate[newint, {z, 0, c}] /. MapIndexed[C[#2] -> # &, constants] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.050616, 0}  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your particular case, the integral is independent of `a` and `b`.

```
Integrate[b*Cos[2*Pi*((z - z1)/c)] + a*Sin[2*Pi*((z - z1)/c)], {z, 0, c}]
    (* gives 0 *)
```

Also, you can check it by playing with the parameters:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[b*Cos[2*Pi*((z - z1)/2)] + a*Sin[2*Pi*((z - z1)/2)], {z, 0, 
   2}], {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {z1, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: the final result does not matters. The problem is that when the coefficients, which normally would be move  out  the integral, make the integration slower if they have some structure, the slowing down increases when the coefficients get more  complicated.